Is there a way to type hint pandas column names?
in a data postprocessing step I am creating a pandas DataFrame df_energy, whos columns are created according to the input data (differing each run). As column names I am using instances of a dataclass ColumnName, which holds information about the data origin.
import pandas as pd
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ColumnName:
    bus_name: str
    component_name: str
    component_type: str

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.bus_name, self.component_name, self.component_type))

# Here an example dataframe. In the actual code the dataframe column names change each run
df_energy = pd.DataFrame({
    ColumnName('bus1', 'comp1', 'type1'): [1, 2, 3],
    ColumnName('bus1', 'comp2', 'type2'): [4, 5, 6],
    ColumnName('bus2', 'comp3', 'type3'): [7, 8, 9],
    ColumnName('bus2', 'comp4', 'type4'): [10, 11, 12],
})

cols_bus1 = [col for col in df_energy.columns if col.bus_name == 'bus1']

print(df_energy[cols_bus1])

I now iterate through the column names and access the dataclass atributes.
cols_bus1 = [col for col in df_energy.columns if col.bus_name == 'bus1']

This works fine when running the code, but mypy is complaining as it expects the column names to be a strings; mypy -> error: "str" has no attribute "bus_name"  [attr-defined]
Is there a way to let mypy know that each column name actually is an instance of that dataclass?
I read into pandera, but as the column names are not fixed and will change each time the code is run, I couldn't get pandera to work. I think I could also get the code running using a MultiIndex for columns, but it feels more readable accessing column information as dataclass properties.

Which version of python are you using?

@SergedeGossondeVarennes python version is 3.12.7, pandas version is 2.2.3


it feels more readable accessing column information as dataclass properties [than MultiIndex levels]

It's not. Look at the version without a MultiIndex:
>>> df_energy[[col for col in df_energy.columns if col.bus_name == 'bus1']]
   ColumnName(bus_name='bus1', component_name='comp1', component_type='type1')  \
0                                                  1                             
1                                                  2                             
2                                                  3                             

   ColumnName(bus_name='bus1', component_name='comp2', component_type='type2')  
0                                                  4                            
1                                                  5                            
2                                                  6                            

Compared to the version with:
>>> df_energy.loc[:, df_energy.columns.get_level_values('bus_name') == 'bus1']
bus_name        bus1      
component_name comp1 comp2
component_type type1 type2
0                  1     4
1                  2     5
2                  3     6

Or this might be more idiomatic (same output):
df_energy.xs('bus1', axis=1, level='bus_name', drop_level=False)

Or possibly, you can go even simpler:
>>> df_energy['bus1']
component_name comp1 comp2
component_type type1 type2
0                  1     4
1                  2     5
2                  3     6

Setup
df_energy = pd.DataFrame({
    ('bus1', 'comp1', 'type1'): [1, 2, 3],
    ('bus1', 'comp2', 'type2'): [4, 5, 6],
    ('bus2', 'comp3', 'type3'): [7, 8, 9],
    ('bus2', 'comp4', 'type4'): [10, 11, 12],
}).rename_axis(['bus_name', 'component_name', 'component_type'], axis=1)

bus_name        bus1        bus2      
component_name comp1 comp2 comp3 comp4
component_type type1 type2 type3 type4
0                  1     4     7    10
1                  2     5     8    11
2                  3     6     9    12


Thanks! My remaining issue with MultiIndex is that while retrieving data works well, I haven't found a convenient way to write new columns while referencing the MultiIndex names. I have to rely on the index level order, e.g. df_energy[("busNew", "compNew", "typeNew")] = 0
With my approach I can do df_energy[ColumnName(bus_name="busNew", component_name="compNew", component_type="typeNew")] = 0. If later on the index levels order changes or new index levels are added, my approach will still work and a default value for new index levels can be set in ColumnName.

@Sillywumps Hmm, yeah, I can't find a convenient option either. Just an idea: maybe xarray would be better able to handle this, since it's meant for working with n-dimensional data. I've never used it myself.
